# The Home page is looking selected even after changing page

Tags: css, html

I am creating a website and I have encountered a problem.
The website has 4 pages: Home, Blog, About and a pop-up Contact. The problem is that when I click on Blog, for instance, it does not get shaded a darker black, and does not look selected. Instead, the Home page looks selected and is in a darker shade of black.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you haven't set the related navbar option to active.

Please provide more information and I will be able to better help you.

For example, if you are using Twitter Bootstrap it is as follows:

```
<li class="active"><a href="http://homelink.com">Home</a></li>
```

That would be if you were on the home page.